# Почему не срабатывает часть кода php-mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   print_r($row);
   echo "Your email is ".$row['email']." And your password is ".$row['password'];
}


$query = "INSERT INTO 'users' ('email', 'password') VALUES ('naf@gmail.com', '12345')";    
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    echo "Удачный запрос";
} else {
    echo "Ошибка запроса";
}
```

Первая половина кода срабатывает, а код ниже (INSERT INTO) выдает ошибку запроса... В чем нюанс?

Comment: Выведите стандартными средствами PHP ошибку на экран. Для ответа на вопрос необходимо знать ошибку, а танцы с бубном не очень хорошее занятие

Comment: Добавил в начале кода   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);      но ошибок нету...

Comment: Используй `mysqli_error`

Comment: Кавычки кривые. Имена таблиц и полей обрамляют не прямой кавычкой, а бэктиком.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте ``` `` ``` при выборке чего-либо/вставки чего-либо.
Вместо `'users'` используйте `` `users` ``